# What CSS can I use to change the color of an individual links hover without changing the others?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Currently the HTML looks like this:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s"></i>
                <p><a class="email" href="mailto:your-email@your-domain.com" style="color: #ffffff; hover:#006b33">sales@higherpromos.com</a></p>
            </div>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
    .col-lg-4 text-center a.email:hover {
color: #006b33;
```

}

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the hover color you will have to change it in a CSS-Style that is correct. But to apply it to only one special element you need to create a special class or map it to an id. Note that you *must* declare the standard color in CSS as well otherwise it won't work.

By Class:

```css
.email {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.specialColor:hover {
  color: #006b33;
}
```

```html
<a class="email specialColor" href="#" style="">LINK</a>
```

By Id:

```css
.email {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#specialColor:hover {
  color: #006b33;
}
```

```html
<a id="specialColor" class="email" href="#">LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a style directly to your anchor. That style is taking precedence over your other styles.
You could use the following style:

```
.text-center a.email {
    color: #fff;
}
.text-center a.email:hover {
    color: #006b33;
}
```

and change your html like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x wow bounceIn" data-wow-delay=".1s"></i>
    <p><a class="email" href="mailto:your-email@your-domain.com">sales@domain.com</a></p>
</div>
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

You're not combining selectors correctly.

```
.col-lg-4 text-center a.email:hover
```

This is nonsensical because you're asking for an element called `text-center` which isn't a valid element. In this particular case you want to use:

```
.col-lg-4.text-center a.email:hover
```

The `.col-lg-4.text-center` part of the selector is combining both class names (selecting an element that has BOTH `.col-lg-4` and `.text-center` applied. But it's probably not necessary. In general you want your selectors to be as nonspecific as possible.